# Control sizing and position will change when form will resize in win form application c#

Tags: c#

suppose i have label and button on textbox and i want that if i resize my win form then my label and button size and position will change. i got the solution in wpf but i am working with win form apps. here i am giving the url from where you can see what kind of output i am looking form. the url is https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeoVK.png. please see the image and tell me how can i implement the same output in win form apps. please help me with code snippet in c#.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider that window forms and WPF are **very** different, especially about the UI management and controls nesting / UI composition.

I have seen some articles describing what you are trying to do now in windows forms, long ego, it's something called control scaling if I recall well.

Answer (score 3):

You should make yourself familiar with the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties of the controls. They are great tools for this kind of work.

Note though that they will alter the size of the controls only, they will not affect font size.

Comment: Fredrik, you are right but he is looking for control scaling, from the picture he has linked you can see the button and label not only change size, width and height, but also font size which means the controls are geometrically scaled...

Comment: @Davide: you are correct. I added that remark while you typed your comment, but you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties for simple stuff and [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) event for more complicated stuff. UI positioning API is much more limited than WPF and you will probably have to do stuff like scaling manually.